# PHP - ZendFramework: How to use Zend_Translate without the whole framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization, translation

i'm building a simple PHP website and want to translate it into 2 languages (spanish,english). 
I've read some questions here and everybody recommend Zend_Translate. I've read the [documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html) and seems pretty good.

I've read I can use the Zend_Translate component without using the entire Framework, just that component, but i cannot. I've tryed everything. I downloaded the framework and placed it in a `libs` subdirectory. And i've tryed severals ways to import it:

```
// First try
require('libs/Zend/Translate.php'); //Fail

//Second try
require('libs/Zend/Loader.php'); //Good
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Translate'); //Fail
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: But you can. It has some dependencies, but doesn't need the entire Framework. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Zend/Translate.php has some requires on the firsts lines that doesn't work. That blow the first try. And the second one has other warnings too.

Comment: so satisfy those requires (as said, it has *some* dependencies). It's still far from needing the whole framework. If that doesn't worj, you need to show what warnings you are getting

Comment: I've tryed, but doesn't work.

Comment: ZF expects the `Zend/` folder to be findable in your path. Check that it is first.

Comment: @gms8994 it worked great. Can you publish an answer with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per @santiagobasulto, I'm creating an answer for this question.

Make sure that `Zend/` is in your path, as the Zend Framework expects that folder to be there.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to this post, I was able to finally make it work!

For people like me who are searching for a working example of using zend_translate without using the Zend Framework, here it is:

https://github.com/26medias/zend_translate

If you are using Windows (like I do), you'll need to install gettext first:
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gettext.htm

To edit the translations:

1. open /locale/[locale name]/messages.po
2. add your translations
3. Execute translate.bat (if you didn't install gettext in the default directory, update the path to the bin folder). It will generate/update the messages.mo file.

And you're done!

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your 'libs' in your include path. It's quite simple :

```
set_include_path( implode( PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
                '/path/to/your/libs',
                get_include_path(),
            )
        )
    );
```